# Play Framework Import Scala files in Build.scala

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

The layout of my project is just like any other Play project except I have a folder of scala files inside of my project folder that I want to use inside of Build.scala

```
projectRoot
   ...
   project[projectRoot-build]
        Build.scala
        plugins.sbt
        scalahelpers
             helpers.scala
```

Then inside of Build.scala... (generalizing a lot here)

```
import scalahelpers._
object ApplicationBuild extends Build
{
    ....
}

object DeploySettings
{
   //Then I use classes inside of helpers.scala in here
}
```

My Build.scala file is working fine when I start the project with the activator command before importing scalahelpers.*, but when I add the import scalahelpers.* sbt says it cannot find object scalahelpers.

It seems there has to be a way to reference scala files similarly to the way you add library dependencies inside of plugins.sbt.  My IDE is seeing scalahelpers just fine and the Build.scala has no errors until I run the activator command.  How do I get it to recognize helpers.scala?  I'm using play 2.3.6.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried moving helpers.scala out of scalahelpers, that is on the same level as Build.scala?